# viewDidLoad UIView with CGPoint()

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview, viewdidload

I want to create my own custom segue animation in which I want to make presenting VC appear from the button.origin at size(1,1) and shift to CGPoint(0,0) and stretch to full screen size.

`VC1` segues to `VC2` and passes `VC1`'s button.frame via

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let PVC = segue.destinationViewController as VC2
    PVC.CGstart = button.frame.origin}
```

in `VC2` I have

```
@IBOutlet var VC4: UIView!

var CGstart = CGPoint()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    VC4.frame.origin = CGstart
}

@IBAction func DragTest(sender: UIButton) {
    VC4.frame.origin = CGstart
    println(CGstart)
}
```

the `viewDidLoad` does not adjust `VC4`'s frame.origin....while my `@IBAction func DragTest` does

Why is this? I've tried so many different variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the issue.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    VC4.frame.origin = CGstart
}
```

no need for `viewDidAppear` or `layoutSubviews`.

Comment: You might find that causes you problems if anything causes a layout to occur after viewDidLoad which is quite likely.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the origin setting to `viewWillAppear`.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    VC4.frame.origin = CGstart
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: Perhaps you have auto layout enabled and it is moving it back based on a constraint. Does it work if you put it in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: putting it in `viewDidAppear` causes `VC4` to load and show then move to `CGstart` which defeats the purpose almost of the animation.

Comment: Well what is shows is that you have an issue with auto constraints being applied during layout which is moving it into a default position. `viewDidLoad` works because this is post layout. I think the solution here is to override layoutSubViews. In here call super.layoutSubViews then set the CGstart.

Comment: only option is `override func layoutSublayersOfLayer(layer: CALayer!)` and even putting it here doesn't change that it's loaded in default then moved.

Comment: Did you try layoutSubviews? That should work as long as you do your change after you call super.layoutSubviews?

Comment: `override func layoutSubviews() {super.layoutSubviews(); VC4.frame.origin = CGstart }` produces errors "method does no override any method from its superclass" and "UIViewController does not have a member named 'layoutSubviews'"

Comment: Apologies. Was looking at UIView. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` should give you the equivalent opportunity. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLayoutSubviews